# For PWA, what is the easiest way to get per-device settings (as in reading a .ini file or environment variables)?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

For PWA, what is the easiest way to get per-device settings (as in reading a .ini file or environment variables)?

I'm making a very simple in-company react PWA for andriod-based tablets (only). I just want to store a couple of settings (the room number where the device is being used, and a device id)  and read those in upon startup.
My experience in recently in Windows, and so I'm imaging a text file that I could place on each tablet with the settings.  Does that make sense for our PWA?
Or is there a better/easier way to do app settings?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how that data is initially provisioned and what kind of guarantees you need about it being "tamper-proof."

Assuming you can provision the information during the web app's initial launch, and you're fine using storage that's exposed via a browser's Developer Tools (i.e. your threat model doesn't include a motivated user using DevTools to erase/modify the data), a simple approach would be to a) use the Cache Storage API to read/write that data as JSON, using a synthetic URL as the key and b) requesting [persistent storage](https://web.dev/persistent-storage/) just for an added guarantee that it won't be purged if the device ends up running low on storage.

This could look like:

```js
// Just use any URL that doesn't exist on your server.
const SETTINGS_KEY = '/_settings';
const SETTINGS_CACHE_NAME = 'settings';

async function getSettings() {
  const cache = await caches.open(SETTINGS_CACHE_NAME);
  const cachedSettingsResponse = await cache.match(SETTINGS_KEY);
  if (cachedSettingsResponse) {
    return await cachedSettingsResponse.json();
  }

  // This assumes a generateInitialSettings function that does provisioning
  // and returns an object that can be stringified.
  const newSettings = await generateInitialSettings();
  await cache.put(SETTINGS_KEY, JSON.stringify(newSettings), {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    }
  });

  // Optional: request persistent storage.
  // This call may trigger a permissions dialog in the local browser, so it is
  // a good idea to explain to the user what's being stored first.
  // See https://web.dev/persistent-storage/#when-should-i-ask-for-persistent-storage
  if (navigator.storage && navigator.storage.persist) {
    // This returns a promise, but we don't have to delay the
    // rest of the program execution by await-ing it.
    navigator.storage.persist();
  }

  return newSettings;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was  so useful. As I used your clues to read up, I came across localstorage, tried it, and it seems to do what I want, for my simple in-house app.  Do you see a problem using this for my situation?  I don't care if it's tamper-proof... it's in-house, and there would be zero motivation to change the setting (a room number)

Comment: `localStorage` is okay for many use cases. You mention that you're making a PWA, which implies that there's going to be a service worker, and I assumed that you might want to read the settings from the service worker. Service workers can't use `localStorage`, but they do have access to the Cache Storage API (and to IndexedDB, which is another option, but more complicated to use). That's the main consideration.